# How I can change my regexp to find multiple urls?

Tags: javascript

When I'm trying to find an url it was detecting only one url how I can change this regexp to find any number urls. please help me. Here is my regexp [URL Regexp](https://regex101.com/r/tl3OsE/1)

Comment: If you would, please post all the code relevant to the question *in the question itself* - don't hide it behind a link. You shouldn't tell potential helpers who would otherwise love to help that they have to navigate offsite just to have an idea of what you're working with. If the link breaks, the question could be rendered useless to future readers. Please edit your code into the question in a [MCVE], or the question might get closed, thanks.

Comment: Are you just looking for `/g`?

Comment: OMG. Thanks. I forgot add `/g`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regexp` in order to separate URLs from given string.

Please check below example :

```js
function getURLList(string) {
    var urlRegex = /(https?:\/\/[^\s]+)/g;
    return string.replace(urlRegex, function(url) {
        console.log(url);
    })
}

var simpleString = "Some line here http://stackoverflow.com https://google.com www.google.com https://www.fb.com https://www.gmail.com";

getURLList(simpleString);
```